# How to install Composer with docker exec

Tags: docker, composer-php, docker-compose, dockerfile

I'm trying to install composer on docker container. I have a container `laravel55` and I'm gonna to install composer insite it.

```
docker exec laravel55 curl --silent --show-error 
https://getcomposer.org/installer | php

#result
Composer (version 1.6.5) successfully installed to: /root/docker- 
images/docker-php7-apache2/composer.phar
Use it: php composer.phar
```

Aftar installation, I'm trying to using `composer` but it doesn't work:

```
 docker exec -w /var/www/html laravel55 php composer.phar install

#result
Could not open input file: composer.phar
```

It seems that Composer had not installed!
How can I install composer on a docker container?

Comment: You should read the [official Docker tutorial on building and running custom images](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/).  You usually _don't_ install software in a running container using `docker exec`, because anything you do will be lost as soon as the container exits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well with your command you're actually installing composer.phar locally on your host, you just execute the curl command inside the container. The part behind the pipe symbol `|` is not executed in your docker container but on your host. In your second command you switch your working directory to `/var/www/html` where you apparently expect the `composer.phar` but not in the first command.

So to make the whole command run in the container, you can try the following:

```
docker-compose exec -w /var/www/html laravel55 \
    sh -c "curl --silent --show-error https://getcomposer.org/installer | php"
```

Comment: It's worked, thank you. I had written `docker-compose` instead of `docker` by mistake so I updated my question.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [official composer image from dockerhub](https://hub.docker.com/_/composer/) and mount on it a volume from your app container

i.e

```
docker run -td --name my_app --volume /var/www myprivateregistry/myapp

docker run --rm --interactive --volumes-from my_app --volume /tmp:/tmp --workdir /var/www  composer install
```

Comment: I'm confused. Does it run `composer install` in `/var/www` ?

Comment: /var/www is a volume from your container app

Comment: As per documentation, this approach is not the best choice since you may need to run scripts at the end of the composer install or you may need some extensions that the built in php in the image does not provice, resulting in errors.

The best approach would be to install composer inside your docker instance as the documentation suggests